# Pandas df.mode with multiple values per cell in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a `Keywords` column. Each cell in that column has 5-10 individual values (comma seperated) which consist of 1 - 3 words. How can I count the most occurring keywords in the column?

I have tried `df.Keywords.mode` but it returns all values for each cell because they obviously don't occur multiple times within each cell.

Here an image to clarify:

[image]

All input is appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what your `df` looks like once it's in pandas? Do you have a column of lists?

Comment: Does *"5-10 individual values (comma-separated)"* mean one big string (as @Jezrael's answer assumed) or lists of 5-10 strings?  Show us `df.Keywords[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` for DataFrame and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then count by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and get top values by [`Series.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.head.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Keywords':['aa,bb,vv,vv','aa,aa,cc,bb','zz,bb,aa,ss']})

N = 5
df1 = (df.Keywords.str.split(',', expand=True)
         .stack()
         .value_counts()
         .head(N)
         .rename_axis('val')
         .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
  val  count
0  aa      4
1  bb      3
2  vv      2
3  zz      1
4  cc      1
```

Another solution if no missing values is flatten splitted lists and count by `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
N = 5
df1 = pd.DataFrame(Counter([y for x in df.Keywords for y in x.split(',')]).most_common(N), 
                   columns=['val','count'])
print (df1)
  val  count
0  aa      4
1  bb      3
2  vv      2
3  zz      1
4  cc      1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The 2nd method with counter is exactly what i was looking for! I'll have to read up on this a bit cause the list comprehension is a bit confusing to me here but that's a fantastic opportunity. Much appreciated!